# magento 1.9.1 database table mg_core_cache_tag went missing

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0

We are running a ecommerce website on `vps machine`, Yesterday suddenly magento trowed an error saying mg_core_cache_tag table is missing from database.

It was very confusing about reason behind it occurrence. Mysql was running but database was not accessible from webmin but was able to access it from command line and came to know that it was available. what we did is dropped the table via command line and added a the table with reference from previous database backup and issue was fixed.

But what would have caused such an issue. we suspect the our server storage capacity was close to full. is it ok to add a table like that will it result in any future issues? what is the correct way to fix database error like this without restoring backup losing data?